# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $f \circ f = f \iff f \upharpoonright rng(f) = id_{rng(f)}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I think the answer is no, because we can take $f(x) = -x$. Then $f \circ f = f$, but $f \upharpoonright rng(f) = - id_{rng(f)} \neq id_{rng(f)}$.

Comment: The $f$ you chose doesn't satisfy $f \circ f =f$, because $f \circ f$ is the identity map

Comment: If $f(x) = -x$, then $$(f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) = f(-x) = -(-x) = x \ne f(x)$$

Comment: Yes, that was wrong idea. Thanks.

Comment: What does $f\upharpoonright rng(f)$ mean??

Comment: @Martund It is the restriction of $f$ to the range of $f$.

Comment: It means restriction to it's image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example satisfies a similar equation: $f\circ f={\rm id}$.

In fact, $f\circ f=f\iff\forall x:f(f(x))=f(x) \iff\forall y\in{\rm range}(f):f(y)=y$.